# Elasticsearch Synonym search using wordnet not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to debug my synonym search .it seems like when i use wornet format and use the wn_s.pl file it doesn't work, but when i use a custom synonym.txt file then it works.Please let me know where i am doing wrong.please find my below index:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "synonym": {
                        "type": "synonym",
                        "format": "wordnet",
                        "synonyms_path": "analysis/wn_s.pl"
                    }

                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "synonym": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": ["lowercase",
                            "synonym"
                        ]
                    }

                },
                "mappings": {
                    "properties": {
                        "firebaseId": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "fielddata": true,
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "name_auto": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },

                        "category_name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "synonym"

                        },
                        "sku": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "magento_id": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "seller_id": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "square_item_id": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "square_variation_id": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "typeId": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do synonym search on category_name ,i have items like shoes and dress etc .when i search for boots,flipflop or slipper nothing comes.

here is my query search:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "category_name": "flipflop"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the tokens generated for your field using the `synonym` analyzer using `_analyze` api

Comment: I don't understand what token you are asking about . i am using postman and i can get other searches fine.also if i use custom synonym file i can get the result.its just when i use wn_s.pl i dont get any result.
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
this is my response

Comment: when you index a document, ES generated a token based on the analyzer you specified and matches this against your search term, if tokens in your index doesn't match the tokens generated by search query then it will not match,  looks like the `.pl` format isn't supported by ES, that's the reason I want to know the tokens which it generated, please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/indices-analyze.html on how to generate tokens

Comment: {
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "this",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}

Comment: can you show the the url of your `_analyze` api and which text and analyzer you used ?

Comment: http://develastic.shopviewtique.com/elasticsearch/test7/_analyze

{
  "analyzer" : "wordnet-synonym-analyzer",
  "text" : "this"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194223/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-datadoctor).

Answer (score 0):

Your wordnet synonym format is not correct. Please have a look [here](https://github.com/buildbreakdo/elasticsearch-wordnet-synonyms)
For a fast implementation please look at the [synonyms.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/buildbreakdo/elasticsearch-wordnet-synonyms/master/synonyms.json)